# Symmetric $3 \times 3$ Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

A symmetric $3\times 3$ matrix $A$ with real number entries satisfies $A^3 = I$. What can you say about the eigenvalues of $A$ and their multiplicity? What can you deduce from that about $A$ itself?

I know that since $A$ is symmetric and real, eigenvalues of $A$ are real. What else can I deduce?

Comment: Suppose $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ with eigenvector $v$. What does $A^3 = I$ then tell you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ with (nonzero!) eigenvector $v$, so $Av = \lambda v$. Applying $A$ to both sides, we get $A^2 v = \lambda Av = \lambda (\lambda v) = \lambda^2 v$. Applying $A$ to both sides again, we get $A^3 v = \lambda^3 v$. Now, we use $A^3 = I$, and this becomes $v = \lambda^3 v \implies 0 = (\lambda^3 - 1)v$. Now $v$ was not $0$, so $\lambda^3 -1 = 0$. That is, $\lambda$ is a third root of unity $\lambda = e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}k}$ for $k \in \{0, 1, 2\}$. But since $A$ is symmetric, all of its eigenvalues (that means $\lambda$!) are real, and hence the only possibility is $\lambda = 1$.

This reasoning was applied for an *arbitrary* eigenvalue, so we see that *all* the eigenvalues of $A$ must be $1$, that is, $A$ has eigenvalue $1$ with multiplicity $3$.

Comment: Better, $A=Id$ ad $A$ is diagonalisable, the only diagonal matrix with $D^3=I$ is $D=Id$, and $A=PIdP^{-1}=Id$

Answer (score 0):

$\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ if and only if $\lambda^3$ is an eigenvalue of $A^3$. Now since $A^3=I$, the eigenvalues of $A^3$ are $1$, so $1$ is also the only eigenvalue of $A$.

Comment: To conclude this, you must use the fact [$A$ symmetric $\implies$ the eigenvalues of $A$ are all real].

Comment: how can you be sure that there are no other eigenvalues and 1 is the only eigenvalue?

Comment: That the only eigenvalue of $I$ is $1$ is trivial. That $\lambda^3=1$ has only one real solution, namely $\lambda=1$, then answers your question.

Comment: @Jon Warneke, OP already mentioned that...

Comment: @EricS. Right, but it should be mentioned in the solution, because without it, $\lambda$ could be some other (non-real) third root of 1.

Answer (score 0):

I got this answer in solutions by my teacher. I was unsure that why $A^3 = 0$ implied that 1 is the only eigenvalue though (not unsure anymore- the answers above explain it.):

The eigenvalues must be real (since $A$ is symmetric) and be cube roots of 1 (since $A^3$ = I). Therefore $1$ is the only eigenvalue. Since by FDST $A$ is diagonalisable we deduce that the geometric multiplicity is 3. Therefore every non-zero vector is an eigenvector and $A$ must be the identity matrix.